# Providing Resources for Supporting Multiple Screens in Libgdx android

Tags: android, libgdx

In android I can supply alternative resources for many screen resolution such as drawable-hdpi, drawable-ldpi, and drawable-mdpi. Will libgdx realize it is working with a certain screen density and use the appropriate resource for it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Libgdx doesn't directly support multi-resolution resources the way Android does. However, Libgdx does have some support. The [ResolutionFileResolver](http://libgdx.l33tlabs.org/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/assets/loaders/resolvers/ResolutionFileResolver.html) class allows you to resolve file names to the best resolution. However, you are responsible for setting the possible resolutions and directory names. There is an example use in the [AssetManagerTest](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/tests/gdx-tests/src/com/badlogic/gdx/tests/AssetManagerTest.java).